# I can't update my binding data(only update at first time)

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to show the stream data to textbox in real time. But the textbox doesn't updated even  the stream data has updated. I don't know what is wrong.

Here is my XAML code.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path = marketPrice}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

And this is View Model code.

```
public class OrderTestViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     public QuotesDataSource DataSource;
     public string _marketPrice => DataSource.SymbolPrice;
     public string marketPrice
     {
         get { return _marketPrice; }
         set
         {
             RaisePropertyChanged("marketPrice");
         }
     }  
     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
     public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
     {
         if (PropertyChanged != null)
             PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
     }   
}
```

I checked the marketPrice is updated real time.

And the last is hidden code.

```
public partial class OrderTest : UserControl
{
   OrderTestViewModel model = new OrderTestViewModel();
   public OrderTest()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       DataContext = model;
   }
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: Is it normal in the setter you trigger the "RaisePropertyChanged" but you never assign the new value ?

Comment: How and where do you set the `marketPrice` property to tell the UI to update?

Comment: Could you explain more detail about your question?

Comment: Does `DataSource.SymbolPrice` have an event or something to tell you (the ViewModel) when it has updated? You're going to need something that that, and then in the handler for that update you can raise the `PropertyChanged` event.

Comment: @CМаксим: I thought it was spot on. You have a property called `marketPrice` that you bind to. Where do you set it? Or when do you expect to see any new value in the UI?

Comment: I want to update new value in UI when `DataSource.SymbolPrice` is updated. `DataSource.SymbolPrice` is updated periodly.

Comment: Then you need a way to determine *when* the update happens. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your marketPrice setter never update the value of _marketPrice (which will always show the same value.

Would you want something like :

```
 public string _marketPrice = DataSource.SymbolPrice;
 public string marketPrice
 {
     get { return _marketPrice; }
     set
     {
         if (_marketPrice != value) 
         {
            _marketPrice = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("marketPrice");
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: `_marketPrice = value;` doesn't work because of  `_marketPrice` is read only.

Comment: But it can never work. You notify the application "marketPrice" changed, so the application will try to get it. In reality behind the "marketPrice" property there is the "_marketPrice" field and that value will never change. You can trigger the "changed" event as many times as you want, the value to display is never updated.

Answer (score -1):

> I want to update new value in UI when DataSource.SymbolPrice is updated. DataSource.SymbolPrice is updated periodly

Then you should bind directly to the `SymbolPrice` property and implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise the `PropertyChanged` event in the `QuotesDataSource` class:

```
public class OrderTestViewModel
{
    public QuotesDataSource DataSource;

    public string marketPrice => DataSource.SymbolPrice;
}
```

Obviously some object must tell the UI *when* there is a update and this is the responsibility of the source object.

The view model cannot be supposed to know when the price is changed in the `QuotesDataSource` unless the latter tells it somehow, for example by raising an event.